# Search results pagination using Laravel Scout

Tags: php, laravel, search, pagination

I have a problem with pagination using use [Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scout) and [TNTSearch driver](https://github.com/teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver). For example, I want to search for the keyword "Product 80." The URL is `localhost/search?keyword=product+80` and when I go to the next page the URL becomes `localhost/search?query=Product%2080&page=2.` It doesn't display anything in the search results. When I manually change the URL to `localhost/search?keyword=product+80&page=2` it works fine, how can I fix it?.

**Searchbar**

```php
<form action="{{ route('products.search') }}" method="get" class="search">   
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="Search">
    <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="mdi mdi-magnify"></i></button> 
</form>
```

**Route**

```php
Route::get('/search', 'ProductController@search')->name('products.search');
```

**Controller**

```php
public function search(Request $request)
{
  $keyword = $request->keyword;
  $products = Product::search($keyword)->paginate(20);

  return view('search.index', compact('keyword', 'products'));
}
```

**View**

```php
<div class="container">
  @foreach ($products as $product)
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ $product->name }}</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  @endforeach

  {{ $products->links() }}
</div>
```

**dd($request->all())**

```
array:1 [▼
  "keyword" => "Product 80"
]
```

**dd($products)**

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#315 ▼
  #total: 100
  #lastPage: 5
  #items: Collection {#340 ▼
    #items: array:20 [▼
      0 => Product {#363 ▶}
      1 => Product {#344 ▶}
      2 => Product {#353 ▶}
      3 => Product {#361 ▶}
      4 => Product {#360 ▶}
      5 => Product {#359 ▶}
      6 => Product {#358 ▶}
      7 => Product {#357 ▶}
      8 => Product {#356 ▶}
      9 => Product {#355 ▶}
      10 => Product {#354 ▶}
      11 => Product {#352 ▶}
      12 => Product {#362 ▶}
      13 => Product {#351 ▶}
      14 => Product {#350 ▶}
      15 => Product {#349 ▶}
      16 => Product {#348 ▶}
      17 => Product {#347 ▶}
      18 => Product {#346 ▶}
      19 => Product {#345 ▶}
    ]
  }
  #perPage: 20
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://marketplace.test/search"
  #query: array:1 [▼
    "query" => "Product 80"
  ]
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
  +onEachSide: 3
}
```

**dd($request->keyword)**

```
"Product 80"
```

**dd($request->query)**

```
ParameterBag {#50 ▼
  #parameters: array:1 [▼
    "keyword" => "Product 80"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show your Product::search function? I'm guessing it might be trying to split off only `+`. `%20` is a space, so you should be able to split off that as well.

Comment: How did query parameter change from `keyword` to `query`? Can you show us your full blade?

Comment: Due to this change aforementioned, `$request->keyword` would have been `NULL`. Hence, there were no results.

Comment: @aynber I use tntsearch, I don't know which function you mean

Comment: please post the output of `dd($request->all());`, `dd($products);`, `dd($request->keyword);` and `dd($request->query);`.

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din I have edited the question

Comment: so what is the problem now?@IndraSukmajaya

Answer (score 0):

In order for the pagination to work correctly, Laravel requires a certain query name. So simply change your html to:

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="query" placeholder="Search">
```

and in your controller:

```php
$keyword = $request->query;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public function results(Request $request)
{
    $request->flashOnly('q');
    $products = Product::search($request->q)->paginate(5);
    $procucts->withPath('results');
}
```

Take a look here [Laravel Documentation Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests)